# Replacing Sriplets by Servlets in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JPS page from which I want to execute a shell script placed on server:
Below code works fine and "/tmp/Sample.sh" script is getting executed on server.

Now I want to do 2 things:

```
1.The script is getting executed as soon as page is loaded, but i want to execute it only when button is clicked.

2.I understand that use of scriplets is discouraged, what I googled is that I should call a servlet, when button is clicked, in which i can move the java code.
```

I'm new to these terminologies as my primary skill is not java. 
I have readed theory of servlet but , not getting how exactly i can achieve above two functionality.
Any help in achieving above two points would be greatly appreciated

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <%
    String unixCommand = "sh /tmp/Sample.sh";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec(unixCommand);
   %>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED CODE AS PER SUGGESTIONS:**

**http://10.111.24.21:7001/Project_1/Test_1.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="location.href = 'http://10.111.24.21:7001/Project_1/JavaServletClass.java';" id="RedirectButton" > Execute</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**http://10.111.24.21:7001/Project_1/JavaServletClass.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class JavaServletClass extends HttpServlet 
{
   public void init() throws ServletException { }
   private void ExampleMethod() throws IOException 
    {
      String unixCommand = "sh /tmp/Sample.sh";
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      rt.exec(unixCommand);
    }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  
    {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      ExampleMethod();
      out.println("<h1>" + "Method Executed" + "</h1>");          
    }

   public void destroy() {  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsp page translates to servlet eventualy so ofc it is possible to do same thong that you did in servlet. If usage of JSP page is absolutely necessery you can do fallowing things:

1. Create servlet follow tutorial on [Create Servlet](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm)
2. create method to execute command

> ```
> private void ExampleMethod() {
>    String unixCommand = "sh /tmp/Sample.sh";
>    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
>    rt.exec(unixCommand);
> }
> ```

3. Call method from doGet

> ```
>    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
>       throws ServletException, IOException {
>
>       // Set response content type
>       response.setContentType("text/html");
>
>       // Call commands
>       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
>       ExampleMethod();
>       out.println("<h1>" + Method Executed + "</h1>");
>    }
> ```

4. Replace scriptlet in body of jsp with:

   > <button onclick="location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/SERVLETNAME';"
   >   id="RedirectButton" > Execute</button>
5. Replace server name, location (localhost:8080) with youre values ...
6. FORGET ALL OF THAT AS SERVLETS AND SCRIPTING IN HTML IS SO OLD AND OBSOLETE IT SHOULD NOT BE USED ANY MORE

Comment: Thanks elrado for the response, i'm trying to implement as per your suggestions and will soon post the outcome. Meanwhile, if "SERVLETS AND SCRIPTING IN HTML IS OBSOLETE" which technology I should use ??

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create a web application which can be deployed in weblogic server and can give user an interface (URL) to click on a button which would run shell script. I only know one way to do this which is creating JSP like this, exporting project as war and deploy in weblogic which seems to be working fine as of now. But if there is any better approach, i would like to know about that as well.

Comment: For quick mockups this tech should be ok, for real usage you should use some Java MVC framework or Javascript MV* framework and JAVA rest. But this depend on the context if you need to be fast and your "thing" are scripts and not real app, you should be OK  :).

Comment: Hey, When I am clicking execute button, its getting redirected to servlet, but then I'm getting Error 404. I have updated the code in the question

Comment: there is mistake http://10.111.24.21:7001/Project_1/JavaServletClass.java. YOu should not reference class but name you gave to servlet in XML config (look at tutorialspoint link I gave you)

Comment: I dispute #6 here.  Servlets may be old, but they are *not* obsolete.  The spec is still being maintained and updated as part of the JavaEE specification.  In fact, all those MVC frameworks are implemented as servlets.  What servlets *are* is much lower level than is typically useful for a medium-to-large application, which makes them hard to use for those use cases.  For very simple use cases, though, they're often much less trouble than the big MVC frameworks.

Comment: @elrado: It worked :) Thanks a lot, you saved my time :). I'm accepting this as answer but I have few more questions related to this. I will post them as separate question. Is there a way i can send you those new question in future ?

Comment: @Ian McLarid might Obsolete is overstatement, but as extensive and long time user of servlets I am getting bashed all the time to use some framework on top of them. And have to aggree that they (frameworks) are elegant. But you are right it does not hurt to know what you are REALLY doing, so thumbsup